# TabLayout not changing item color when switching

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, android-architecture-navigation

I have a tabLayout with an icon, the selected tab highlights the icon as red, but the other tab has also the icon as red, and I want to change that icon color when switched to that tab, instead the two icons are always red

```
 val tabLayoutMediator = TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
            TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->

                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        tab.text = "tab1"
                        tab.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.ic_fork)

                    }
                    1 -> {
                        tab.text = "tab2"
                        tab.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.ic_basket)
                    }
                }

            })
        tabLayoutMediator.attach()
```

XML

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create bg_tab.xml file in the drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/red" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

and set drawable using tabBackground properties

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/bg_tab"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/red" />
```

Comment: This changes the whole tab background, not just the icon

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:tabIconTint="@color/your_color_selector"
     app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/selected_color"/>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/selected_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/unselected_color"/>
</selector>
```